# When dynamically linking, where will it search for the library, and how to change this?

Tags: unix, g++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

When I'm dynamically linking on a Unix/Linux based system, where will it try to find the library files when I execute the program, and how do I change this? I am using the GNU/G++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system the program runs on defines where to search for the dynamic libraries.  The program itself just names the libraries (without path).

On Linux systems there is a system-wide default where to search and you can override this by setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a colon-separated list of paths to the libraries:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/libs/:/another/path/to/libs/of/mine/
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ./path/to/my/executable
```

or shorter:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/libs/:/another/path/to/libs/of/mine/ ./path/to/my/executable
```

The system default is configured using `ldconfig` and typically based on the files found at `/etc/ld.so.conf` (pointing to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`) and `/etc/ld.so.cache`.

Which dynamic libraries a given executable is going to need can be examined using `ldd`:

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc83ff000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fbe1306b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbe12e63000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fbe12c5a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe1289b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbe12697000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe132ae000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbe12479000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fbe12274000)
```

You can also use the output of `strace` when starting the executable to see where the system looks for libraries:

```
$ strace ls 2>&1 | grep '^open.*\.so'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Comment: So I could do something like #define LD_LIBRARY PATH "/usr/lib;/usr/local/lib;./lib"?

Comment: No, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable.  Set and export it in the shell before starting your executable.  I will extend my answer accordingly.

Comment: You _cannot_ specify in your executable where to search for the dynamic libraries.  That's against the idea behind it.

Comment: Just a note: There are UNIX systems where the variable name is different eg. on AIX: LIBPATH

Comment: Yep, thanks for that addition, Ingo.  Stated in my answer is a specific situation on Linux system.  Other systems might as well not allow rerouting via environment variables.  There are too many flavors to be sure.